# UIGestureRecognizer within UITableViewCell

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, uitableview, uigesturerecognizer

In my UITableViewCell I had the UISwipeGestureRecognizer to swipe images in cell and I'm stuck. E.g., GestureRecognizer calls to method, that increment images count and reload the row. How to define the row that was touched and pass it's number to method?

Comment: Can you include some code? The method where you handle the swipe would be nice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found, that we can define swiped cell thru touch coordinates. It seems like this:

```
if (recognizer.state == UISwipeGestureRecognizerStateEnded) {
    CGPoint gestureLocation = [recognizer locationInView:self.tableView];
    NSIndexPath *swipedIndexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForRowAtPoint:gestureLocation]; 
//found IndexPath for swiped cell. Now we can do anything what we need. 
//In my case it's cell reloading with new image in UIImageView.
NSArray *rowsToReload = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:swipedIndexPath, nil];
[self.tableView reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:rowsToReload withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationNone];
```

Comment: Your if statement is missing its closing bracket, where exactly should it go?

Answer (score 0):

Probably you should disable cell selection - that usually triggers cell reloading.